# geoxml3: z-index issues and changing cursor on mouseover

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geoxml3

I'm currently working on a Google Maps API v3 project and I'm using geoxml3 to load some kml files which have polylines. However, I'd like to use the API's kmllayer option to load a kml file which has only markers (it's much faster than geoxml3).

First problem: the geoxml3 polylines are always above the markers, and I can't find a way to give a higher z-index to the kmllayer. Markers behind polylines don't look so good.

Second problem: the cursor changes to the link-hand every time it goes over the polylines loaded via geoxml3. Is it possible to specify another cursor on mouseover?

The test page is http://www.cicloviaslx.com/indexs4.html. Enable the "Parques" checkbox to see the z-index problem. Sorry for the messy code, but I have a lot of testing going on.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can customize your cursor by using
 `body { cursor: url(mycursor.cur) }`

or, to do it on hover use
 `body a:hover { cursor: url(mycursor.cur) }`